# Enable Google experiment permanently

Tags: google-search

I love the Google Keyboard shortcuts search [experiment](http://www.google.com/experimental/).
*Note: the original link died, this archived page appears to refer to it: https://web.archive.org/web/20110508074540/http://www.google.com/experimental/.  Image from that page:*

[image: snapshot]

However, it seems to live locally on my machine. Is there any way to enable this permanently whenever I'm logged into my Google account?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly controled by a cookie so your solutions:

- find & manually copy the cookie to the other computers
- use a portable browser on a usb key
- use the [weave extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/10868) (for firefox) or a similar
- use [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or a similar service to synchronize your profile browser (or only the cookie) between computers (here a [tutorial for firefox & dropbox](http://jonefox.com/blog/2009/11/16/how-to-sync-firefox-across-multiple-computers-using-dropbox/))